# Producing a sleep log visualisation in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have a data-set of sleep-time information and would like to produce a visualisation of it using Python.

The `.csv` data-set I have looks like the this:

`SleepStartDate,SleepStartTime,SleepStopTime
17/03/2017,23:45,07:25
19/03/2017,01:05,09:10
19/03/2017,23:50,08:25`

The visualisation I want to produce should be similar to the following:
[image: Sleep time log visualisation. Source: http://quantifiedself.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/qs2.png]
Image source: http://quantifiedself.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/qs2.png

I know this is a really simple visualisation, and imagine that it's built into some already existing library, but my best Googling efforts have been unable to locate it. I'd much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Comment: Quick google search points to [`plot.ly`](https://plot.ly/python/). Looks like you may need to look at the [scatter plot](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/) section.

Comment: Thanks. plot.ly looks great. Should have what I'm looking for, though I'm not sure I'll find it in the scatter plot section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic Python choice would be to use the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) package. Looking at your sample graph it looks like a vertical bar graph.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I think I'm going to give plot.ly a go first, as it seems to be a bit prettier and better documented.

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't able to find a library with functionality to do what I wanted, so ended up writing a script to do it for myself:

**Script:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import datetime as dt
import csv
import sys

MINUTES_IN_DAY = 1440.0
COLUMN_COLOUR = 'b'

# Graph data using matplotlib visualization
def plotData(data,columnColour,maxDate,minDate): 


    # Set up an invisible background scatterplot give graph the correct size
    # Make a series of events that are one day apart 
    x = mpl.dates.drange(minDate,maxDate,dt.timedelta(days=1))

    # Offset first event to top of graph to give correct height
    x[0] += 0.85

    # Extract the time using a modulo 1, and adding an arbitrary base date
    # int used so that y-axis starts at midnight
    times = x % 1 + int(x[0])
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Daily Sleep Patterns', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Set background scatterplot to invisible 
    ax.plot_date(x, times, 'ro', color='w', visible=False)

    ax.yaxis_date()
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    start, end = ax.get_ylim()

    # Fix division sizes and labels to show hours on y-axis
    hourDivision = 1.0 / 24.0
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start,end,hourDivision))
    ax.set_yticklabels(['Midnight','1am','2am','3am','4am','5am','6am','7am','8am','9am','10am','11am','Midday','1pm','2pm','3pm','4pm','5pm','6pm','7pm','8pm','9pm','10pm','11pm','Midnight'])

    # Iterate through data 
    for i in range(0,len(data)):

        # If period starts and finishes on different days, slit and add to both days
        if data[i].startTime > data[i].stopTime:

            currentDataItem = data[i]

            currentDate = dt.datetime(currentDataItem.year,currentDataItem.month,currentDataItem.day)
          
            currentDate -= dt.timedelta(days=0.5)

            tomorrow = currentDate + dt.timedelta(days=1)
            
            plt.axvspan(xmin=currentDate, xmax=tomorrow, ymin=currentDataItem.startTime, ymax=1, facecolor=columnColour, alpha=0.5)


            theDayAfterTomorrow = tomorrow + dt.timedelta(days=1)


            plt.axvspan(xmin=tomorrow, xmax=theDayAfterTomorrow, ymin=0, ymax=currentDataItem.stopTime, facecolor=columnColour, alpha=0.5)

        # Else, add to given day
        else:

            currentDataItem = data[i]

            currentDate = dt.datetime(currentDataItem.year,currentDataItem.month,currentDataItem.day)
          
            currentDate -= dt.timedelta(days=0.5)

            tomorrow = currentDate + dt.timedelta(days=1)
            

            plt.axvspan(xmin=currentDate, xmax=tomorrow, ymin=currentDataItem.startTime, ymax=currentDataItem.stopTime, facecolor=columnColour, alpha=0.5)

    ax.set_ylabel('Hours',fontweight='bold')

    #ax.legend()
    ax.grid(True)

    plt.show()

# Read data from csv file
def readDataFromFile(dataFile):
    f = open(dataFile,'rt')
    listOfInputLists = []
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            listOfInputLists.append(row)
    finally:
        f.close()
    return listOfInputLists

# Class to store time and date data read from file
class sleepInstance(object):
    def __init__(self,listOfInputLists):
        self.day = 0
        self.month = 0
        self.year = 0
        self.formatDate(listOfInputLists[0])
        self.startTime = self.formatTime(listOfInputLists[1])
        self.stopTime = self.formatTime(listOfInputLists[2])

    # Extracts date information variables
    def formatDate(self,unformattedDate):
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(unformattedDate,"%d/%m/%y")
        self.day = int(date.strftime("%d"))
        self.month = int(date.strftime("%m"))
        self.year = int(date.strftime("%Y"))

    # Formats time as a decimal fraction of day, for use in graph
    def formatTime(self,unformattedTime):
        timeSinceMidnight = dt.datetime.strptime(unformattedTime,'%H:%M:%S')
        midnight = dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
        minutesSinceMidnight = ((timeSinceMidnight - midnight).total_seconds() / 60.0)
        fractionOfDay = minutesSinceMidnight / MINUTES_IN_DAY
        return fractionOfDay

# Formats data read from file as a list of sleepInstance objects
def formatDataForPlot(listOfInputLists):
    sleeps = []
    for i in range(1,len(listOfInputLists)):
        sleeps.append(sleepInstance(listOfInputLists[i]))
    return sleeps

# Extracts earliest (min) and latest (max) dates from data, for use in setting graph limits
def getMaxAndMinDates(plotDataList):
    dateTimeList = []
    for item in plotDataList:
        nextDate = dt.datetime(item.year,item.month,item.day)
        dateTimeList.append(nextDate)
    maxDate = max(dateTimeList)
    minDate = min(dateTimeList)
    return maxDate, minDate

dataFile = 'sleepData.csv'
listOfInputLists = readDataFromFile(dataFile)
plotDataList = formatDataForPlot(listOfInputLists)
maxDate, minDate = getMaxAndMinDates(plotDataList)
plotData(plotDataList,COLUMN_COLOUR,maxDate,minDate)
```

**Input:**

```
Date,Start,Finish
17/03/17,03:15:00,03:55:00
17/03/17,06:20:00,06:35:00
17/03/17,09:00:00,09:40:00
17/03/17,13:10:00,13:35:00
17/03/17,15:45:00,16:30:00
17/03/17,18:45:00,19:25:00
17/03/17,21:15:00,21:35:00
18/03/17,00:30:00,02:00:00
18/03/17,04:50:00,05:05:00
18/03/17,08:20:00,08:40:00
18/03/17,12:30:00,13:10:00
18/03/17,16:30:00,17:00:00
18/03/17,18:45:00,19:00:00
18/03/17,20:30:00,21:00:00
19/03/17,00:00:00,12:00:00
19/03/17,18:00:00,23:59:00
19/03/17,13:00:00,14:00:00
20/03/17,12:00:00,11:00:00
```

**Output:**

[image: Output graph of sleep data]

May fancy it up a bit when I have time: https://github.com/ambidextrous/timeLogGrapher